# Which of iOS apps allow customizing font size?

Tags: ios, font, resolution, accessibility

Which of iOS apps that allow customizing font sizes:

- either through support of DynamicType / LargerText system settings (and BoldText that can be helpful to improve readability)
- or have their own settings for font size--and how broad is the size range available?

One of the goals for such a list is to help understanding how font sizes can change when switching between devices with different DPI and resolution--given current variety: iPad Mini/Air, [iPhone 6/6+, earlier iPhones](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147244/how-font-sizes-at-iphone-6-6-compare-to-earlier-iphones).

Ideally I'd be happy to compare screenshots, but doubtful how it can be achieved here at SE with reasonable efforts.

Comment: Posted this after [discussion at meta](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/listing-ios-apps-supporting-dynamictype-ok-how). Will populate with the details on dozen or two that I collected myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(please contribute to the list with any other apps, and feel free to edit to make the list more accurate--this is a community wiki answer)

---

Notation for the list below:

1. With few exceptions, any app falls into on of these categories:

   - it supports System Settings > Dynamic Type and Bold Text (I mark it as **"Dynamic&Bold"** below)
   - OR also supports System Settings > Larger Text (I mark as **"Larger Text"**)
   - OR has its own app-specific font size settings (**"App settings"**)
   - OR has NO font size customization whatsoever (**"No customization"**)
2. For each app, I also specify how its maximum text size compares to standard system apps at maximum Dynamic Type setting if different (the app font is **Smaller** or **Larger** than in system apps)--to make it easier for a given app to understand its text size limit, given only few minutes with built-in apps only at Apple outlet.

---

## Social networks

**Facebook**: 
 - all UGC (News Feed, User Timeline, Individual post and comments): Dynamic&Bold ([since 2015-Nov-06](https://www.facebook.com/accessibility/posts/997008960342829)); much Smaller 
 - app interfaces: No customization; smaller

**Twitter**: 
 - timeline: App settings (3 sizes); smaller 
 - settings screen: Dynamic&Bold

**Google+**: No customization; Much smaller

**Instagram**: No customization; Much smaller

**VKontakte** (both iPad- and iPhone apps): No customization; Smaller

---

## Email apps

**Mail**: 
 - plaintext emails: Dynamic&Bold 
 - HTML emails: font scales only with Larger Text, but not with Dynamic Type(!); but can be much smaller than for plain text emails / than in other apps

**GMail**:  No customization; Smaller (both for plaintext and HTML emails)

**Google Inbox**:  No customization; Smaller (both for plaintext and HTML emails)

**AirMail**: Dynamic Text, App Settings; no LargerText support (text gets smaller instead)

**Calendar** (by Apple): Dynamic&Bold

---

## Task managers

**OmniFocus**:
- Dynamic&Bold throughout the app
- LargerText for leaf-level outline items and Note editing only; No for outline groups

**Things**: No customization; smaller

---

## Instant Messengers

**Messages** (iMessage):
- history of chat with a contact: LargerText
- list of contacts on left sidebar: Dynamic&Bold

**Skype**: No customization; Much Smaller

**Telegram**:
- history of chat with a contact: Dynamic Type (no Bold Text); smaller
- list of chats: No customization; Smaller

---

## Web browsers

**Safari**:
- regular browsing: No customizaion; pinch to zoom leads to horizontal scrolling. Smaller.
- has a special Reader Mode with App Settings: wide range of sizes, comparable to the range of Larger Text. Works only for article-type web pages, not everywhere.

All other browsers tried (**Google Chrome**, **Opera**, **Yandex Browser**, **iCabMobile**): No Customization; pinch to zoom leads to horizontal scrolling. Smaller.

---

## Office documents

**Google Drive**: No Customization

**Google Docs**: No customization: only document zoom, leads to horizontal scrolling. Smaller

**Google Sheets**: No Customization: only document zoom, leads to horizontal scrolling. Smaller

---

## Maps

**Google Maps**: No customization; Smaller

**Apple Maps**: Dynamic Type only

---

## Other built-in apps

**Settings**: Dynamic&Bold

**Notes**: LargerText

**Reminders**: LargerText

**home screen**: No customization

**built-in keyboard**: Bold Text only

---

## Other third-party apps

**Pocket**:
- list of articles: Dynamic&Bold
- aricle body: App settings: wide range of sizes, comparable to the range of Larger Text

**Google Keep**: No Customization. Much Smaller.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, assuming you know the risks and have a backup, there are some utilities on Cydia which can change fonts that various iOS apps use.  However, you have to jailbreak your device to use them.

Just bringing this up as an alternative.